# how do i redirect only root using htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I currently have a subdomain i need to keep in tact: www.sub.domain.com

I also have a sub directory at www.domain.com/blog that needs to remain in tact

It's an annoying setup because I am using shopify which is 3rd party hosted using CNAMES. my shop is on shop.domain.com, and my blog is on domain.com/blog

I want to redirect ONLY root / domain.com (both www and non-www), but not if they land on anything after the / (a blog post for instance). its going to redirect to the subdomain.

This is what i have currently

```
ErrorDocument 404 /index.html
RewriteEngine on
rewritecond %{http_host} ^domain.com [nc]
rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [r=301,nc]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this?

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ <wherever you want to send the redirect> [NC,R=301]
```

Comment: Note that in .htaccess the leading slash is removed so the ReqriteRule pattern `^/$` will never match. Replace with just `^$` to get the result you want.

Comment: Ulrich - good catch, and you're completely correct.  Answer updated appropriately.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem and this htaccess code is working for me

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub\.domain\.com [NC] #root
RewriteRule ^$ http://www.newsite.com/news-trends/ [NC,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub\.domain\.com$ [NC]  #else
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.newsite.com/blog/$1 [L,R]
```

Answer (score 0):

This should go!

```
# First we turn the rewriting engine on
RewriteEngine on

# Then we check if the host is the right one
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (www\.)?domain\.com [NC]

# Then we make sure only the home page is considered
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$

# Then we redirect wherever we want!
Rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://othersite.com/ [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Just wondering... how do you find threads like 4 years old? Lol